dimension formula for kernels of two commutative linear maps
Let $f, g$ be two linear maps on $V$, a finite dimension vector space. Under the condition $fg=gf$, my question is that does the following formula holds?
$$
\mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{ker} f \cap \mathrm{ker}g)  + \mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{im} f+\mathrm{im} g) = \dim V.
$$
Here $\mathrm{ker}, \mathrm{im}$ denote the kernel and images respectively.
The above is certainly not hold for general $f,g$, so I add the commutative condition.

What's the question?

I edited slightly. @azif00
